# Label text in datarepeater

Tags: c#, label, web-controls, datarepeater

I am trying to use a label in my datarepeater, when I am able to bind data and write to me html page.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%></asp:Label>
```

which works fine.

When I try to get text value I get "".

Label lblcurrentID = ri.FindControl("lblID") as Label;

result: 
lblcurrentID.text = ""

this same code works fine for the dropdownlist that I have in the datarepeater.  I am wondering if this has anything to do with the label being converted to a span tag.

```
<span id="template6_middlecontent1mAzoaNominationApproval0_dataReaper_ctl01_lblID">2009040100000888213</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ran into this issue before, I don't recall actually finding a solution to the problem, as a work around, I used an `<asp:HiddenField>` to hold onto the information for me:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hiddenId" value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
```

Note the ' instead of " wrapping the Eval statement btw, .NET is fussy when you're assigning values to server controls.

Answer (score 0):

**you need bind lblD.Text with the value** not like

<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>